# Is there a --disable-web-security fix for recent changes of Chrome ~70?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I do cross-origin, cross-frame scripting in one of my projects (end to end testing with client side js without selenium) and that project highly relies on the `--disable-web-security` flag. From today one of my tests is failing. It tries to load a non-existent remote URI to a child window to check whether an error is thrown by the lib. Well I got an error, but that is a security error, so not what I expect. The other tests are between the karma server on `localhost:9876` and a node server on `localhost:4444`. Those are working properly. My karma contains a Chrome custom launcher with the flag:

```
    customLaunchers: {
        "ch": {
            "base": "Chrome",
            "flags": ["--disable-web-security"]
        }
    },
```

As far as I know it needs some sort of user dir too, but the Karma launcher fills that param. Any idea about whether I can fix this or at least what release of Chrome changed the behavior? (I have already sent a bug report.)

Note that the question has nothing to do with Karma. All it does is starting Chrome from CLI with the given flags. A possible fix would be adding another flag, like the `--user-data-dir` was, but I guess the current changes are intentional and they cannot be undone. I'd like to see where this was discussed. I only found a 5 years old topic in Chromium Google Gorups which discusses this: https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/forum/#!msg/chromium-dev/iivpdszNY3I/3o3BF_mGwlIJ

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `--disable-site-isolation-trials` is a partial solution. It works on `https://www.google.com`, but does not work on Chrome error pages with the `error://` protocol.